# How do I perform a function in sequential dynamic ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

VBA newbie here.  I did find some information out there about coding these loops but I'm having a very hard time figuring out if and/or how it applies to my specific needs, so thank you in advance for any help you can give.

In order to QA information before it's formatted and uploaded, I want to cycle through multiple groups of dynamic ranges and check the information against another column within that range.  Each range is grouped by an email address in column D, and I need to make sure that the same email is also listed in column G (I am going to delete columns B-D before upload).  Since each grouping could be anywhere from 1 to 100 rows, I have coded how to define the ranges (below), but how can I add a loop to perform the check in each group individually?

The output for all of this should be a message box that either says, "All clear!" if the code finds no errors, or "[Name] isn't listed.  Please add their information before continuing." if they aren't listed.

I'm assuming I should do some sort of Do While or Do Until or For loop for this, but then I get confused conceptually on whether to declare my variables in or outside of the loops and then how to concatenate possibly multiple unlisted names into the same message box at the end.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub QANameIsListed()
'Declare the variables.
Dim nRow As Long
Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long
Dim sEmail As String
Dim sName As String

'Figure out what first email address is.
sEmail = Range("D2").Text

'Figure out where first group data starts.
For nRow = 1 To 65536
    If Range("D" & nRow).Value = sEmail Then
        nStart = nRow
    End If
Exit For
Next nRow

'Figure out where first group data ends.
For nRow = nStart To 65536
    If Range("D" & nRow).Value <> sEmail Then
        nEnd = nRow
    End If
Exit For
Next nRow
nEnd = nEnd - 1

'Check whether the name is listed in the second column.
With Range("G" & nStart & ":G" & nEnd)
sName = Range("B" & nStart).Text & " " & Range("C" & nStart).Text
    Set c = .Find(sEmail)
    If c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox (sName & " " & "isn't listed." _
        & "  " & "Please add their information before continuing.")
    Else
        MsgBox ("All clear!")
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no real question in your post. :) However, here's my take.

First, you are placing your `Exit For` in the wrong place. If you place it outside the `If---End If` block, then your `For` loop will always exit before it reaches the `Next nRow`.

Second, you are looping through 65536 cells twice, which is not only resource intensive, it's not completely compatible as well. If my data was in row 65537, I'd totally evade the loop. In Excel 2007 onward, after all, there are a million available rows.

My suggestion is, use `Find` exclusively. We'll use it to find the first occurrence of `sEmail` from the top and the last occurrence of `sEmail` from the bottom. We'll return their row index for this. Of course, this works only with the assumption that your emails are sorted properly...

The final part is very simple, but it can escape some beginners, so no worries there. What we do is, we declare the range as determined from the above, and we will loop inside this range. You were almost there, so that's excellent.

My modification of your code is untested, but it captures what you tried to achieve and then maybe some. There are some lines I took the liberty of completely removing as I found them unnecessary (`Set c = .Find(sEmail)`, for one). I also added some other "newbie-friendly" things, like a `Boolean` check and the quick and dirty method for multiple lines in a `MsgBox`.

Code follows:

```
Sub QANameIsListed()
'Declare the variables.
Dim nRow As Long
Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long
Dim sEmail As String
Dim sName As String
Dim cRng As Range, cL As Range 'BK201: Declare cRng.
Dim rStr As String 'BK201: For multiple unlisted names.
Dim aClr As Boolean 'BK201: To check if it's all clear.

'Figure out what the first email address is.
sEmail = Range("D2").Value

'Figure out where first group data starts.
nStart = Range("D:D").Find(sEmail).Row

'Figure out where first group data ends.
nEnd = Range("D:D").Rows.Find(What:=sEmail, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'BK201: Set the target range.
Set cRng = Range("G" & nStart & ":G" & nEnd)

'BK201: Set a default value for aClr.
aClr = True

For Each cL In cRng
    'Similar to B and C.
    sName = cL.Offset(0, -5).Value & " " & cL.Offset(0, -4).Value
    If cL.Value = sEmail Then
        'Do nothing. Let the loop continue.
    Else
        aClr = False 'BK201: Oops. At least one entry isn't listed.
        rStr = rStr & sName & vbNewLine
    End If
Next cL

If aClr Then 'BK201: If all is clear...
    MsgBox "All clear!"
Else 'BK201: Otherwise...
    rStr = "The unlisted names are:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & rStr
    rStr = rStr & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please add their information before continuing."
    MsgBox rStr
End If

End Sub
```

This doesn't end here, though, since this will only run properly for one email on your list, and that email is also located in `D2` which is where `nStart` is going to default to anyway. So, even with the code above, my next suggestion is: It's better to have a list of all unique emails somewhere else, then iterate over that, with `sEmail` being equal to the email string of the current iteration.

If this sounds nice, then let us know so we can apply it accordingly. Otherwise, this code will work correctly on your current set-up or request as it is. :)

Result of test with `sEmail` located in `M2` rather than `D2` below:

[image: Similar set-up.]

**MASSIVE EDIT:**

As per exchange with OP, the following should do the trick. Please note however, that for my convenience, I took the liberty of assuming that a list of unique e-mails of all team leaders are located somewhere. Modify the code as necessary. Code follows:

```
Private Sub CheckIfLeadExists()

    'Dimension area.
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim rMem As Range
    Dim vList As Variant, vElement As Variant
    Dim lStart As Long, lEnd As Long
    Dim sEmail As String, sName As String, rStr As String
    Dim bClear As Boolean

    'Assignment area.
    Set wSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
    vList = wSht.Range("J2:J4").Value 'Assign the unique e-mails to a variable.
    bClear = True 'Default value of boolean check for clear run.

    For Each vElement In vList 'Iterate over the e-mails.
        sEmail = vElement
        With wSht
            'Find the starting row for current e-mail of loop.
            lStart = .Columns("D").Find(sEmail).Row
            'Likewise, find the ending row for current e-mail of loop.
            lEnd = .Columns("D").Find(sEmail, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            'Get the lead's name.
            sName = .Cells(lStart, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(lStart, 3).Value
            'Assign the member's area to a range.
            Set rMem = .Range("E" & lStart & ":G" & lEnd)
        End With
        'We now search this member's area for the current lead's e-mail.
        If Not rMem.Find(sEmail) Is Nothing Then
            'E-mail exists in member's area. Do nothing.
        Else
            bClear = False 'Oops. At least one entry isn't listed.
            rStr = rStr & sName & vbNewLine 'Add to string.
        End If
    Next vElement

    If bClear Then 'If all is clear...
        MsgBox "All clear!"
    Else 'Otherwise, list them all.
        rStr = "The unlisted names are:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & rStr
        rStr = rStr & vbNewLine & "Please add their information before continuing."
        MsgBox rStr
    End If

End Sub
```

Screencap of result:

[image: Should be perfect now.]

**LAST EDIT (HOPEFULLY):**

Following code takes into account not having the list in advance. This will create the list in Column J instead.

```
Private Sub CheckIfLeadExists()

    'Dimension area.
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim rMem As Range
    Dim vList As Variant, vElement As Variant
    Dim lStart As Long, lEnd As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim sEmail As String, sName As String, rStr As String
    Dim bClear As Boolean
    Dim oDict As Object, vMails As Variant, vItem As Variant
    Dim lCount As Long

    'Assignment area.
    Set wSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.

    'Get first all the emails with duplicates. Modify as necessary.
    vMails = wSht.Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    'Create a dictionary.
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With oDict
        For Each vItem In vMails
            If Not .Exists(vItem) And Not IsEmpty(vItem) Then
                .Add vItem, Empty
            End If
        Next vItem
    End With
    'Copy unique list of e-mails to column J.
    lRow = oDict.Count
    wSht.Range("J2").Resize(lRow, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(oDict.Keys)
    vList = wSht.Range("J2:J" & lRow + 1).Value 'Assign the unique e-mails to a variable.
    bClear = True 'Default value of boolean check for clear run.

    For Each vElement In vList 'Iterate over the e-mails.
        sEmail = vElement
        With wSht
            'Find the starting row for current e-mail of loop.
            lStart = .Columns("D").Find(sEmail).Row
            'Likewise, find the ending row for current e-mail of loop.
            lEnd = .Columns("D").Find(sEmail, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            'Get the lead's name.
            sName = .Cells(lStart, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(lStart, 3).Value
            'Assign the member's area to a range.
            Set rMem = .Range("E" & lStart & ":G" & lEnd)
        End With
        'We now search this member's area for the current lead's e-mail.
        If Not rMem.Find(sEmail) Is Nothing Then
            'E-mail exists in member's area. Do nothing.
        Else
            bClear = False 'Oops. At least one entry isn't listed.
            rStr = rStr & sName & vbNewLine 'Add to string.
        End If
    Next vElement

    If bClear Then 'If all is clear...
        MsgBox "All clear!"
    Else 'Otherwise, list them all.
        rStr = "The unlisted names are:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & rStr
        rStr = rStr & vbNewLine & "Please add their information before continuing."
        MsgBox rStr
    End If

End Sub
```

Results are the same. Hope this helps!

**FOLLOW-UP EDIT:**

When dealing with dictionaries, since it is not always you encounter a dictionary with only one item (at least in my experience), `Transpose` is usually the best way to print out the keys or items to a range. However, with only one item in the dictionary, it fails to print it out (never bothered checking *exactly* why). However, looping through the keys or items is just fine and should result into printing out that lone key/item. See following edit.

```
Private Sub CheckIfLeadExists()

    'Dimension area.
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim rMem As Range
    Dim vList As Variant, vElement As Variant
    Dim lStart As Long, lEnd As Long, lRow As Long
    Dim sEmail As String, sName As String, rStr As String
    Dim bClear As Boolean
    Dim oDict As Object, vMails As Variant, vItem As Variant
    Dim lCount As Long

    'Assignment area.
    Set wSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5") 'Modify as necessary.

    'Get first all the emails with duplicates. Modify as necessary.
    vMails = wSht.Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    'Create a dictionary.
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With oDict
        For Each vItem In vMails
            If Not .Exists(vItem) And Not IsEmpty(vItem) Then
                .Add vItem, Empty
            End If
        Next vItem
    End With
    'Copy unique list of e-mails to column J.
    lRow = 2 '--Changed this.
    For Each Key In oDict.Keys '--Changed this as well.
        wSht.Range("J" & lRow).Value = Key
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Next Key
    vList = wSht.Range("J2:J" & lRow + 1).Value 'Assign the unique e-mails to a variable.
    bClear = True 'Default value of boolean check for clear run.

    For Each vElement In vList 'Iterate over the e-mails.
        sEmail = vElement
        With wSht
            'Find the starting row for current e-mail of loop.
            lStart = .Columns("D").Find(sEmail).Row
            'Likewise, find the ending row for current e-mail of loop.
            lEnd = .Columns("D").Find(sEmail, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            'Get the lead's name.
            sName = .Cells(lStart, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(lStart, 3).Value
            'Assign the member's area to a range.
            Set rMem = .Range("E" & lStart & ":G" & lEnd)
        End With
        'We now search this member's area for the current lead's e-mail.
        If Not rMem.Find(sEmail) Is Nothing Then
            'E-mail exists in member's area. Do nothing.
        Else
            bClear = False 'Oops. At least one entry isn't listed.
            rStr = rStr & sName & vbNewLine 'Add to string.
        End If
    Next vElement

    If bClear Then 'If all is clear...
        MsgBox "All clear!"
    Else 'Otherwise, list them all.
        rStr = "The unlisted names are:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & rStr
        rStr = rStr & vbNewLine & "Please add their information before continuing."
        MsgBox rStr
    End If

End Sub
```

Results are the same on multiple groups, and it will not error out when only one group is present.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: The message box string list is great!!  I was having trouble conceptually trying to figure out how to do that, but `rStr = rStr & sName & vbNewLine` is great and super smart.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  I don't have 10 rep so I'm not able to post images yet.  Going off of your example you posted, BK201 should only be listed once in Column G for every row that it is listed in Column D (if at all).  What I need is if it is _not_ listed in G, that's the name that should pop up.  BK201 should also always have the same name associated with it.  Then there is another group of BK200s in Column D that have different emails in Column G, but BK200 should also be listed (once), and on and on.  Does that make sense?  I know, it's dumb, but that's what I have to work with...lol.

Comment: @jfkenne: When checking against Column G, should it only be found in the same range as `cRng`? For example, if my `cRng` is `D5:D10`, should the e-mail only be in `G5:G10` or it could be anywhere in G? Also, second. Should the e-mail in G be *strictly* one or *at least* one?

Comment: It should only be found in `cRng`.  The email may appear multiple times in Column G (in a different group), but I don't necessarily care about that.  The way the user inputs data is to list the group leader's name in Columns B:D next to every member of that group in columns E:G, including themselves.  Occasionally the leader forgets to add themselves in the "Member" column (Column G), which is the reason for this quality check.  Therefore, for each `cRng`, the email in G should be _strictly_ one, but that email may appear in G in multiple groups.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @jfkenne: It does, but bear with me as I have some trouble imagining your data set as well. ;) Confirm if my designations are correct: Column B, C: Name of leader; Column D: Email of leader; Column E, F: Name of members, Column G: E-mails of members. Leader should also be part of Members area, so we're basically checking if the user in charge of inputting the data also included the leader in Columns E-G, yes? :)

Comment: Yes, exactly!  The part I'm having difficulty with is telling Excel to do the following: Look for first group of data, then check if leader is in column G. Look for second group data, check if leader. Look for third group data...etc.  At end of all of it, give MsgBox detailing if everything was good, or listing all leader names that were not listed in their respective group's member data.

Comment: @jfkenne: That actually made it much easier for me. The trick here is not to think always in loops. Looking at the member's area as a block rather than as a list is better, at least for your purpose. Check my code above. This works perfectly, but you have to have a unique list of the e-mails of the team leaders. :)

Comment: @jfkenne: The above code hasn't taken into consideration two things: (1) That there is only strictly one team lead email in the member's area for the group, and (2), that there are multiple instances of the team lead's email across groups. For (1), is it going to be a problem if team lead's email is listed twice in a group? Would the presence of multiple instances mean that some other member wasn't added? For (2), it's vastly inconsequential IMO. We're only looking at the group of member's data one by one anyway so there's no need to check the other groups.

Comment: So close!! The sample data in your screenshot is exactly what it should look like, so thank you for working to interpret that correctly. Now comes the sad part: We work with hundreds of companies and the list of leaders could be any of their employees.  In order to have a list of unique emails, we would literally have to hold every company's entire global address book on file, which is impossible. As per your two things: 1) Is probably okay, but I can look into that on my own. 2) You are correct and it's irrelevant. I've been continuing to try different things as well -- here's hoping!

Comment: If it's easier, this could be two separate steps. One to find all the unique emails in Column D and make a list off to the side like you have, and two to do exactly what you coded. I'll look into that...

Comment: @jfkenne: Elementary, my dear Watson. Already prepared for it. See my edited code.

Comment: Miss and/or Mister BK201, you are simply a genius.  This works flawlessly!!!  I am so, so grateful to you for helping me out with this.  This is much more complicated coding than I would have been able to accomplish on my own, so I am very appreciative of your time.  If you aren't completely exhausted of dealing with me yet, I would love to chat with you to better understand the reasoning behind what you did so I can hopefully replicate similar solutions in the future (I will PM you).  Thank you, thank you, thank you =)

Comment: Update! This code has been working perfectly for dynamic ranges EXCEPT in cases where there is only one group, then I get a Type Mismatch error.  I tried circumventing this by adding `If vList > 1 Then` before the `For Each` part of the code, and in the case that `vList <= 1`, it just checks if D2 = G2. I thought that would work, but I'm still getting the error which makes me think it's happening when it's setting up the dictionary. I'm very unfamiliar with dictionaries -- could you please help diagnose my error?

Or if this should be a new topic altogether, please let me know =)

Comment: @jfkenne: No need to start a new topic--it's like soliciting for rep for a minor edit that I should have pointed out before. ;) Check the last code above and check the ones noted as changed. You'll understand it right away. ;)

Comment: Perfect again =).  Thanks for all your help, BK201!